# Assistance with converting Java to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c

I am trying to convert some code to Objective-C from Java and I'm getting stumped on converting the Java Generic portions. For example, the class declaration in Java I believe is saying that the current class extends any class that is the subclass of the Component class, in Objective-c does this mean you just extend the Component class?

Any assistance that someone could provide would be greatly appreciated. Moving forward with this will help me convert other pieces of the code that are similar. Thanks

Java:

```
public class ComponentMapper<T extends Component> {

private Class<T> classType;

public ComponentMapper(Class<T> type, World world) {
    this.type = ComponentTypeManager.getTypeFor(type);
    this.classType = type;
}

public T get(Entity e) {
    return classType.cast(em.getComponent(e, type));
}
}
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface ComponentMapper : Component
{
    ComponentType* componentType;
    EntityManager* entityManager;
    id classType;
}

- (id) init:(id) componentType World:(World*) world;
- (id) get:(Entity*) entity; // can this just return Entity instead

@end

@implementation ComponentMapper 

- (ComponentMapper*) init:(id) type World:(World *) world {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // should be a call to getEntityManager()
        self->entityManager = [world entityManager];
        self->componentType = [ComponentTypeManager getTypeFor:type];
        self->classType = type;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id) get:(Entity*) entity
{
    return [classType cast:[em getComponent:e param1:type]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Using `Class<T>` is an idiom in Java, it is designed to battle type erasure of Java generics. This is one of these cases when you should be really careful to avoid translating the idiom "word-for-word", because the chance of ending up with nonsense is really high around these areas. The best approach is to try to use the existing design as an inspiration, rather than a template, for your new project. It worked very well for me when I was translating Java to C# - admittedly a much closer fit, but still far enough to justify major refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics were created to add compile-time type safety to collections and parametrized classes. In a statically typed language like Java this can be very useful, but much more less so in Objective C which is dynamically typed and has dynamic dispatch.

I would advise you simply drop generic placeholders when converting from Java, and replace generic return types/arguments with *id*.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, the class declaration in Java I believe is saying that the current class extends any class that is the subclass of the Component class

Nope, `ComponentMapper<T extends Component>` means the class `ComponentMapper` can be parameterized with any class that extends `Component` (or `Component` itself). Thus you could do `new ComponentMapper<MySpecialComponent>` etc.

At runtime that generic information is erased resulting in a `ComponentMapper<Component>`), i.e. the compiler would see `public T get(Entity e)` as `public MySpecialComponent get(Entity e)` whereas after type erasure at runtime it is just `public Component get(Entity e)`.

Besides that `ComponentWrapper` and  `Component` have a *has-a* relationship, i.e. `ComponentWrapper` has a member of type `Component.class` (or `Class<Component>`, which means the same: not a `Component` instance but a reference to the class itself) . Extending would be a *is-a*  relation.

Comment: Ok, so this means that ComponentMapper contains a list of Components or sub-types of Components? So in Obj-c I shouldn't extend component, but hold a reference to it?

Comment: @user1106500 I don't actually know, since there's some code missing (`World` isn't used, `em` isn't declared etc.). It seems like the wrapper actually just gets the component from somewhere (is `em` an `EntityManager`?) and casts it. Depending on what `em.getComponent(e, type)` actually does you might need another solution or don't need `ComponentWrapper` at all. Let me state one important thing: _Before you attempt to port code into another language you should know what it actually does, not just guess._ So first understand the logic of the Java code, then port it to Objective-C.